# How to fetch selected row from seesaw/table

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, seesaw

I have created seesaw/table as below

```
(def table (seesaw/table :model [:columns [:uid :name :price :qty]
                                 :rows [{:uid "1" :name "book1" :price "20" :qty "2"}
                                        {:uid 2 :name "book2" :price "40" :qty "2"} ]]
                          :selection-mode :single))
```

Thereafter I created a top-bottom-split panel and added above created table and a new button to it. Now on click event of button, I want to have selected row/item of table. Code am trying is as below

```
(defn tableButtonwidget1 [](let [top (seesaw/vertical-panel :items [table])
    bottom (seesaw/vertical-panel :items [(seesaw/button :text "Rent"  
    :listen [:action  (fn [e](if-let [s (:selection table)]
                                (println "Current selection is " s)
                                (println "No selection")))])])]
    (seesaw/top-bottom-split top bottom)))
```

but every time I get is "No selection" though I select row, can anyone guide me what mistake am making?

Comment: Have you tried posting to the seesaw mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/seesaw-clj)?

Comment: Now I posted to mailing list you suggested, Thanks